# Did the original X-wing Starfighter have a fifth thrust source?

Tags: star-wars, history-of

It is well known that X-wings Starfighters are driven by 4 fusial thrust engines mounted on each wing but in an early 1975-76 Star Wars concept art by Joe Johnston and an original painting by Ira Gilford for Cinefantastique Magazine - Star Wars Special Issue #24 (Vol6 No.4 / Vol7 No.1) it can be seen what appears to be a fifth thrust source where, actually, the power generator with ionization reactor and s-foil servo actuator are found. I ask if the forgoing art could mean that the original X-wing was conceived with a fifth thrust source.

[image: Front and back covers of Cinefantastique Issue 24]

[image: 1975-1976 Joe Johnston x-wing concept art]

I have also noticed that in the 1st US 1977 printing film movie poster of Star Wars by Thomas Jung, styles A and B, it can be seen a fleet of X-wing Rebel Starfighters where fire appears to propelled them from a single central thrust.

[image]

Comment: There's obviously more wrong with this poster - the TIE (Twin Ion Engine) fighter clearly has only one engine.

Comment: If that bottom image really is concept art for the movies, then doesn't that answer your question?

Comment: Maybe they're [PIE fighters](https://www.darthsanddroids.net/episodes/0889.html).

Comment: @Harabeck - Johnston’s image shown in my question is one of several sketches for the movie but he also draw similar sketches with the actual X-wing rear mean (s-foil components). Unfortunately the sketches are not arranged chronologically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]if you check colin cantwell's concept models (the very first x-wing design), you will see the fifth thruster there too.

Comment: Can you provide some evidence to back this up?

Comment: this would be a better answer w/ a source or image

Comment: ...like this: https://borg.com/2019/01/22/concept-artist-colin-cantwell-reveals-images-of-earliest-star-wars-ship-models-from-1975/

Comment: or - https://colincantwell.com/prints-large/

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! As suggested by others you can [edit] the question to add sources and images. While you're there you can tidy up the question with capitalisation and the like. For more hints as to what makes a good answer, check out the [tour] and visit the [help].

Comment: In post-WEG RPG and model illustrations, the fifth is generally identified as the power generator and ionization reactor exhaust. Whether exhaust provides thrust to the X-Wing wasn’t ever really detailed. It may have been intended as fifth drive, for while in Legends canon wasn’t, and I have no idea re: it’s current nu-canon.

Comment: @SillybutTrue Ionization does provide some thrust even if not intended to be a primary means. There are real-life engine designs that are based on ion thrust.